# Understanding situation with multiple overlapping indexes in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

Given the following indexes for an Oracle database:

```
CREATE INDEX subject_x1 ON subject (code);
CREATE INDEX subject_x2 ON subject (code, status);
```

Is it true that the first index is redundant, and can be removed. We need to get this right as this is a relatively large sized table that is going to be constantly hammered.

Any oracle documentation explaining or confirming this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As with most database questions, it depends :-)

In fact, it shouldn't be removed in *all* circumstances. If you have a query that uses `code` alone in the `where` clause, it's possible that the use of `subject_x1` will still outperform `subject_x2` just by virtue of the fact that less index data will need to be read in.

An extreme example, let's say that `code` is a `char(2)` and `status` is a char(4094)`. If you have the query:

```
select code from tbl where code > 'dd' and code < 'gg';
```

That's most likely to result in an index-only scan since there's absolutely no reason to go to the table. If you use `subject_x1` and you read in 4K blocks from your index, you can bring in a couple of thousand codes with every read.

By using `subject_x2`, each read only gives you one code (and possibly a wasted status). That's a huge difference in performance.

However, and I cannot stress this enough, *measure, don't guess!*

Profile your queries (and updates) using both indexes to see which performs better, and do it with representative data. If you find that `subject_x1` gives you better performance for some queries, leave it in. It will affect the update/insert speed and storage requirements but you'll find that won't generally matter since:

- the vast majority of databases are read far more often than written; and
- most complaints about databases have to do with speed rather than storage space.